# System.IO.FileSystemInfo.Exists' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#

I tried to make a program that will delete a file buy I'm getting a `System.IO.FileSystemInfo.Exists cannot be used like a method` exception when I run the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        FileInfo HealthIcon = new FileInfo(@"Holo\Normal\hud_health.texture");                      
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"hud_health.texture"); 

        ///hud icons textures(Normal)                                      
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) ///Health icon normal
        {
            ///Health icon textures(Normal)
            if (HealthIcon.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\PAYDAY 2\assets\mod_overrides\HoloHud\guis\textures\pd2\hud_health.texture"))
            {
                file.Delete(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\PAYDAY 2\assets\mod_overrides\HoloHud\guis\textures\pd2\hud_health.texture");
            }
            HealthIcon.CopyTo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\PAYDAY 2\assets\mod_overrides\HoloHud\guis\textures\pd2"); ///Health icon Normal 
        }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-invocable member 'System.IO.FileSystemInfo.Exists' cannot be used like a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459343/non-invocable-member-system-io-filesysteminfo-exists-cannot-be-used-like-a-met)

Answer (score 3):

[`FileInfo.Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a *property* not a *method* as the error indicates. It indicates if the file you associated with the `FileInfo` structure (by passing that path when you created it) actually exists.

So all you need to do is check it:

```
if (myFileInfo.Exists)
{
}
```

If you want to check a *different* path, then you need to use [`File.Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which *is* a method:

```
if (File.Exists(myPath))
{
}
```

Or if you meant to delete the file associated with the `FileInfo` structure:

```
myFileInfo.Delete();
```

As an aside, in the very next line, you should be using `File.Delete` instead of `file.Delete` (which probably isn't compiling either).

Please make sure you understand the difference between the `File` and `FileInfo` classes, as it seems to be causing you a great deal of trouble.

Comment: @Steve True, it needs to use the `static` method off the `File` class.

Comment: or just `HealthIcon.Delete()` For the OP I recommend to spend a little time to read and understand the documentation of FileInfo, otherwise this chain of duplicate question will never end.